# I have a pyqt mainwindow how can i load fonts in QlistWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

there is a `QFOntComboBox` class but i want to load all fonts in `QListWidget` named "list". How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

```
import sys,
form PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
class widget(QtGui.QMainWindow):
         def __init__(self,parent=None)
              QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
              list=QtGui.QListWidget()
              ????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

...
allFonts = QtGui.QFontDatabase().families()
stringList = QtCore.QStringList(allFonts)
listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget().addItems(stringList)
...
```

Do not name your `QListWidget()` "list" because it is reserved name!